# continuous functions between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_\ell$

Tags: general-topology

Is there a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ell}$? How about the other way around from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Is there a homeomorphism between those two spaces? Here $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ denotes lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: At the risk of seeming naive, what is $\mathbb{R}_\ell$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Oh I should make that clear. It's the lower limit topology on the real line. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3):

The constant functions (both $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_\ell$ and $\mathbb{R}_\ell \to \mathbb{R}$) are continuous, as is the identity $\mathbb{R}_\ell \to \mathbb{R}$.

There is no homeomorphism, since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected while $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is not (take $(-\infty, 0)$ and $[0, \infty)$).

Comment: Are constants functions between any topological space always continuous?

Comment: Yes -- if $f : X \to Y$ is constant then for any open $U \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U) = \varnothing$ or $X$.

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: yes, but only dumb ones. The only continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_\ell$ are constant functions. This is because $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is *totally disconnected*. Since the continuous image of a connected space (like $\mathbb{R}$) is connected, the claim follows.

To your second question: no. Since $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is totally disconnected, while $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, they cannot be homeomorphic.

---

I hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it now.